# Favorite questions and answers from the last quarter of 2019

Tags: discussion, answers, questions

Too late this time but we are back again.

Following the tradition, we would ask the community to link your favorite questions and answers created from **1st October to 31st December**.

You can search all eligible [questions](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aquestion+created%3A2019-10..2019-12) and [answers](https://movies.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aa+created%3A2019-10..2019-12) posted in the past quarter. Since, we received  501 questions and 696 answers, here are some data queries to make the decision process easier.

- [Questions with the most number of votes from the last quarter of 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738289/questions-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/10/01)
- [Questions with the most number of views from the last quarter of 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738288/questions-with-most-views-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/10/01)
- [Answers with most number of votes from the last quarter of 2019](https://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/738290/answers-with-best-score-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2019/10/01)

The above questions and answers are only for your hint. Feel free to mention any question or answer you enjoyed reading. Since **this is not a competition**, there's no need to mention one question or answer per one answer. Also don't hesitate to mention questions and answers you posted yourself which you think didn't get the appreciation they deserved.